# Structured grid with irregular shape in PETSc (DM context)

Tags: c, matrix, fortran, petsc

I have a finite diference problem in structured grid in `PETSc`, and `DM` context helps me to create the matrix really easy, `DM` give me a whole matrix of rectangular domain that is good to me because I'm using this reference system, but I have an irregular shape in my problem, it means that I'm not using a lot of entries in this matrix. How can I do to don't allocate this space in the matrix assembling and tell `KSP` context not to use this entries to solve the problem?

My code is something like this:

```
DMDACreate2d()
DMCreateMatrix()
DMDAGetCorners()

! loop along the local matrix
DO i,1,width_y 
    DO i,1,width_y
        IF (IsInsideProblemDomian) THEN
            SetMatStencil()
            MatSetValuesStencil()
        END IF
    END DO
END DO

MatAssemblyBegin()
MatAssemblyBegin()
```

Comment: The straightforward way to solve the problem is to set the corresponding entries of the matrix to the identity, that is to set 1 in the diagonal and 0 elsewhere in the lines. To reduce the allocated space for the matrix, the function [`MatXAIJSetPreallocation()`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatXAIJSetPreallocation.html) can be used instead of `DMCreateMatrix()`. The implementation of `DMDAPreallocateOperator()` in petsc-3.5.2/src/dm/impls/da/dapreallocate.c can be modified to this end.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention. Do not use the versions when they play no role in the question!